# PMF from Ewen's Sampling Formula

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, summation

Given the joint mass function

$P(m_1, ..., m_n) = \frac{n!(\alpha - 1)!}{(n+\alpha -1)!}\prod^n_{j=1}\frac{\alpha^{m_j}}{(j!)^{m_j}m_j!}$

How do I calculate the distribution of $Y = \sum^n_{i = 1} m_i$?

I really don't know where to start with this question, please give me some hint.

Answer (score 0):

Find the marginal pmf of $m_i.$ Next, use the convolution theorem to find the pmf of $m_1+m_2,$ say, and see if this can be generalized to more than 2 random variables. Start and if you get stuck...show us the progress and we will help. Also, please specify the domain of the random variables.